# Partial concave maximization of subset of variables

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $f(x_1, \dots, x_N)$ be a concave function in $x_1, \dots, x_N$. For arbitray $n>1$, prove that the (constrained) truncated function defined by
$$g(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}) = \max_{x_n, \dots, x_N \geq c} f(x_1, \dots, x_N),$$
where $c$ is a constant, is necessarily concave in $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}$.

Comment: That's not actually a "concave subset". This is just a partial maximization.

Comment: May I also assume that you meant to write $f(x_1,\dots,x_N)$ (with a capital $N$)?